# how should create schemas for several mongoose models with different fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Suppose we want to build an e-commerce website that includes different products and for example these products are divided into four or five categories. Each category of products has its own fields and of course there are a series of common fields among them such as product name, price, description and ...
My question is, should we define four or five different schemas for each kind of product?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you should create one schema for each category of products, even though they may share some similar fields.

You can create one object for the similar fields and insert them into the Schema if it helps to not have to repeat yourself.

If one Schema have all the fields that all the products need, it would be too bloated. And it won't make sense to have different Models for each category too. When you query for a product, it will return many fields which do not relate to the product.

Comment: so how should I implement add to cart section?
in the user model I add a cart field like this:
.
.
.
cart: {
    items: [
      {
        productId: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Product',
          required: true
        },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true }
      }
    ]
  }
and according to what you said, what should I put in "ref" instead of "product"???

Comment: can I use an array of refs?

Comment: I see your dilemma. In this case, you will have different schemas for storing and listing your products. And a separate product orders schema to store product orders added to the cart - this will be the refs for your cart model. 

The reason is when you have added the products to cart, the fields you require for products should be similar now, like "qtyOrdered", "totalPrice", "unitPrice". You should still ref the individual product category if you wish.